# Setting secure cookies

Tags: 7, cookies

In scanning a Drupal 7 site with Qualys, we're getting the issue

> 150122 Cookie Does Not Contain The "secure" Attribute

Is there a way to systematically add the Secure vs HTTPOnly flag to cookies? Would [Secure Cookie Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/secure_cookie_data) serve this? If so, how do I test that Cookies are secure?

Moreover, this site automatically forwards to https. The user spends no time over port 80 but instead is directly shuttled to 443. We have an administrator who wants nothing but to see this test passed; regardless of the previous fact.

**The Cookie in Question:**

`has_js=1`

[image]

Would the following in settings.php be sufficient:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I can tell Apache to do this for me:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

Which cookie is this? All of Drupal 8's cookies are secure.

The exception is BigPipe's no-JS cookie, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2678628 — but there are no security consequences there.

If that's the one that is triggering this alert, then the problem is clear: your security testing tool is making blanket statements that don't make sense.

Comment: I've adjusted my question to denote Drupal 7.

Comment: I just got this finding from our security scan on Drupal 8 also.